# Change selected cell after type text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel File, I need to insert an scanned barcode into selected cell and after that I need to select the next cell no the below cell. For example:

Current selected cell = A1, Barcode scanned and inserted. Current selected cell now should be B1 instead A2.

I tried adding a textbox and works fine but I found a problem. If my barcode is for example 20010 my code split one number and inserts in one cell. So instead of having in A1 20010 I have 2, in B1 0, in C1 0 in D1 1 and in E1 0.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox1.Activate
   End If
End Sub
```

PD. I don’t know the barcode length. Never it’s gonna by the same.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanners are usually programmable to enter either a carriage return or a tab after it scans, but if you're dead set on using VBA to accomplish this, you could get rid of your textbox and use this in the Worksheet code of the sheet you're scanning into:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Row = 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want it to move from Column A to B to C regardless of row number then change the above to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, this is worth mentioning as well, just in case anyone stumbles across this, `Target` and `ActiveCell` are not the same in a `Worksheet_Change` event. `Target` will always be the cell previously active to `ActiveCell` where `ActiveCell` is now the newly active cell. Try it out. EDIT: to clarify, my code actually says _if and only if the **TARGET** cell row is 1_.

Comment: I tried using your code instead of mine but its giving me an enter action and changes to below cell instead of next cell.

Comment: Pd. This needs to work in cell A1, B1, A44, etc. In all cells

Comment: Do you have the code in a module or in the Worksheet object of the worksheet you're scanning into? And what you're saying is you need a scan into Column A to move focus to column B regardless of what row it is?

Comment: In the worksheet object. It’s an example... if I scan into A1 next selected cell should be B1, if scan into K44 next selected cell should be L44, etc.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!